# Convert Depth First search to Depth Limited Search

Tags: java, depth-first-search

This is my complete code in java, i would like to apply Depth limited search on it. Can someone please help me?

output: S>A>B>C>D>G

Note: S(0) = Start, G(5) = Goal
The depth first search is applied using adj matrix.

```
import java.util.Stack;


public class DFS {

Stack<Integer> st;
  int vFirst;

  int[][] adjMatrix;
  int[] isVisited = new int[6];

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] adjMatrix = {
           //S, A, B, C, D, G, 
            {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0},
            {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0},
            {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
            {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0},
            {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
            {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0},
             };


  new DFS(adjMatrix);

}

public DFS(int[][] Matrix) {

     this.adjMatrix = Matrix;
     st = new Stack<Integer>();
     //int i;
     int[] node = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
     int firstNode = node[0];
     depthFirst(firstNode, 6);



      }

      public void depthFirst(int vFirst,int n)
      {
      int v,i;
      char out=' ';

      st.push(vFirst);

      while(!st.isEmpty())
      {
          v = st.pop();
          if(v==0)out='S';
          else if(v==1)out='A';
          else if(v==2)out='B';
          else if(v==3)out='C';
          else if(v==4)out='D';
          else if(v==5)out='G';

          if(isVisited[v]==0)
          {
              System.out.print("\n"+out);
              isVisited[v]=1;
          }
          for ( i=0;i<n;i++)
          {
              if((adjMatrix[v][i] == 1) && (isVisited[i] == 0))
              {
                  st.push(v);
                  isVisited[i]=1;
                  if(i==0)out='S';
                  else if(i==1)out='A';
                  else if(i==2)out='B';
                  else if(i==3)out='C';
                  else if(i==4)out='D';
                  else if(i==5)out='G';
                  System.out.print("-> " + out);
                  v = i;
              }
          }
          }
}
}
```

Comment: What kind of help do you need?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a temp class or ADT, to store current distance from start up to the node, when you stack them up(push), you add curr distance +1 (distance = 0 at beginig). When you pop, check if distance is greater or lower than the max, and proceed or not. This is what i think.

```
Curr Node,Curr Distance ->  Stack   <-
1st (S,0)               -> (A,1) (C,1)
2nd (C,1)               -> (A,1) (B,2) (D,2)
3rd (D,2)               -> (A,1) (B,2) (A,3) (G,3) 
4....                   -> ....
```

(Might Wanna keep track, which ones are in the stack or not...)

Hope you understood my suggestion, let me know what you think.

Comment: I don't know how to apply it because it's defined as adj matrix, maybe i need to create another class called as Node ? May you please help to modify my code in order to further understand what you're trying to convey.

Comment: No no no, imagine the Node is the index in the matrix, like if you want to go from i to j, you are in row i, and in column j is the value, so you push:
(i, curr_distance+1)

Answer (score 0):

You already have a parameter `n` in `depthFirst` which you are not using, decrement `n` every time `depthFirst` is called and return when `n==0`.

Comment: The parameter **n** should be used in **for(i=0;i<n;i++)** . My mistake for not changing it back.